# How do I change the visual of a form after it has Initialized C# Visual Studio Windows Form App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to build test apps for practice. I work with forms and realised that I can't change the form appearance that already used `InitializeComponent()` in C# Visual Studio App.

My code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form1 form1 = new Form1();
   form1.Size = new Size(50, 50);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In this button1_click, you are already inside Form1 object instance, so use this keyword to access the current Form1 instance. But if you created another one, what youre changing is the brand new one you created inside the handler, which is never shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form1` is a brand new form, whose size you're setting, but which you're never showing.

All you need is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Size = new Size(50, 50);
}
```

Actually, the `this` is redundant, but makes it a bit clearer which form you're changing.